# RegEx for linked images of certain class

Tags: php, regex

I don't have access to an HTML parser on my server, so I need to do this via RegEx and PHP. I want to match all occurrences of linked images of a certain class within a large content string.

Here's a sample taken out of the larger content string that I want to match:

```
<a href='url'><img width="150" height="150" src="url" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="Description" /></a>
```

This seems to match class="attachment-thumbnail"

```
(class=("|"([^"]*)\s)attachment-thumbnail("|\s([^"]*)"))
```

This seems to match everything from the opening HREF to the closing HREF, but it also gets other images in the larger content string that don't have class="attachment-thumbnail"

```
/(<a[^>]*)(href=)([^>]*?)(><img[^>]*></a>)/igm
```

How can I combine the above two to match only those HREFed images of class="attachment-thumbnail"?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is your input output?

Comment: PHP has various built in HTML parsers

Comment: My input would be the entire HTML source of a page, and my output would be the same HTML source, just stripped of all linked images of class="attachment-thumbnail" - like the below example: <a href='url'><img width="150" height="150" src="url" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="Description" /></a>

Comment: You should be able to do that pretty easily with `DOMDocument`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
$html = '<a href="http://www.google.com"><img width="150" height="150" src="url" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="Description" /></a>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $item)
{
    $doc->saveHTML($item);
    if ($item->getAttribute('class') == 'attachment-thumbnail')
    {
        echo $item->getAttribute('src');
    }
}
```

To remove all elements that match the class 'attachment-thumbnail':

```
$html = '<a href="http://www.google.com"><img width="150" height="150" src="url" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="Description" /></a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query('//div[contains(attribute::class,"attachment-thumbnail")]') as $elem)
{
    $elem->parentNode->removeChild($elem);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);
```

Comment: Hi Erik- I just tried it, and my script failed--is DOMDocument included in all PHP installs? I'm on GoDaddy, so, if not, I may not have access to it. Also, what I want to do is output the HTML stripped of all those linked images of attachment-thumbnail class. Is there a way to reverse your code to output everything except those? Thanks!

Comment: @user64391 it should be included by default, http://php.net/manual/en/dom.requirements.php. What PHP version are you running? What error message do you receive?

Comment: $html = '<a href="http://www.google.com"><img width="150" height="150" src="url" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="Description" /></a>';


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query('//div[contains(attribute::class,"attachment-thumbnail")]') as $elem)
{
    $elem->parentNode->removeChild($elem);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);

Comment: @ErikFlitman If you need to update your answer please use the `edit` link. Code shouldn't go in the comments unless it is very short, it is hard to read here.